# Qt C++ SLOT on_returnPressed on_OK_ckicked strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, behavior, slots

I have a strange behaviour with one of my ui`s:

In my ui I have a **lineEdit Shift_x** and a Button **pb_OK**.  When I do the following I have different behaviour:

1. **Edit + RETURN:**
   When I edit the value in Shift_x and press return the slot on_lne_Shift_x_returnPressed() is executed. This is what I would expect. But after that the slot on_pb_OK_clicked() is also executed which in the end  makes my program on_MoveCurve_ValueEdited to be executed twice.
2. **Edit + OK:** If I edit the value in Shift_x and click “OK” only the slot on_pb_OK_clicked() is executed ( which then starts on_lne_Shift_x_returnPressed(); where the actual shift is triggered)

**Why would the program run on_lne_Shift_x_returnPressed()  and   on_pb_OK_clicked()  when I only press the return button?**

Thanks for your help!

This is my code:

2 slots:

```
 void MoveSeries::on_lne_Shift_x_returnPressed()
 {
     const QString arg1= ui->lne_Shift_x->text();
     shift_tracker = shift_tracker-arg1.toDouble();
     emit x_returnPressed(arg1, ChartSeries);
 }


void MoveSeries::on_pb_OK_clicked()
 {     on_lne_Shift_x_returnPressed();     }
```

And a CONNECT in my other class

```
connect(  MOVE_SERIES  , SIGNAL( x_returnPressed( QString ,  QVector < Series*>   )),
              this,SLOT( on_MoveCurve_ValueEdited ( QString,QVector < Series*>))) ;
```

Comment: You could check if the button's `default` or `autoDefault` properties are true. In a dialog a default button will be triggered on "return pressed"

Comment: Thanks !!!  That was it